# Understanding SURF point-of-interest localization

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I've recently read Herbert Bay's paper of SURF. From which I understand:

- SURF calculates a table from each image pixel's Hessian matrix's
  determinant, instead of SIFT's Difference-of-Gaussian table. Then
  SURF finds local maximal (not extremal) by comparing each determinant
  to its 8 neighbors in the same scale, and 18 neighbors from 2 nearby
  scales. Finally, SURF interpolates the maximal point to find the
  exact position of the point of interest.
- In the detecting part, SURF uses 9×9 approximations of second-order
  Gaussian derivatives, combine with an integral image to fast
  calculate the determinant of each image point's Hessian matrix. The
  calculation for each derivative of the Hessian matrix is done by
  placing the correct 9×9 filter center point to an image pixel **x**,
  and simply multiplying corresponding points of the filter and the 9×9
  sub-image whose point **x** is the center (points that are off image
  equal to 0), then calculating the sum of all those multiplications.

Did I take something wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is unclear what your question is and to what do you refer to? Who is they? What is the reference / where did you get this information from? Take your time to derive the background of your question and point out clearly what the actual question is.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how SURF point-of-interest localization works. I'm assuming there are people who read Herbert Bay's paper of SURF that would read this post and help me. Did my question make you hard to understand, even in case you read Bay's paper?

Comment: You should add this information to your question and make clear where you quote.

Answer (score 0):

You're right.
At the end, SURF was about going around the patents of SIFT by altering some steps yet keeping the same idea.